# How can I more efficiently use the Python REPL for package development?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-packaging

### My current workflow

1. I install my package in [editable mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html) (usually in a virtual environment):

   ```bash
   > python -m pip install -e .
   ```
2. I write some code in `pkgfoo/pkgfoo/bar.py`:

   ```
   # Example directory structure

   pkgfoo/
   ├── dev/
   │   └── dev.py
   ├── pkgfoo/
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   └── bar.py
   ├── pyproject.toml
   └── setup.py
   ```
3. I spin up the python REPL and start running some testing code to see if my package is working. Usually this code lives in a folder like `dev`, often getting turned into unit tests later on:

   ```bash
   > python
   ```

   ```py
   # pkgfoo/dev/dev.py

   import pkgfoo as pf

   # Does this work?
   pf.bar.baz()
   ```
4. Once I'm done testing, I quit python using `quit()`, then repeat the process starting at step (2).

### Issues I'm having

- Rerunning `>>> quit()`, `> python`, `>>> import pkgfoo as pf` every time I want to test my code gets tedious, and isn't good for my hands.
- Each cycle, any python objects I've been working with in the previous cycle are lost, so the code I'm able to use for adhoc testing has to be be very short and quick to run so as not to encumber my workflow.

**I'm interested in any answers which solve these issues.** I'm not wedded to VSCode, but I'd prefer to keep using it as my editor if possible.

### What I've tried

- Instead of restarting python, I've tried reloading my package using `importlib`:

  ```py
  # pkgfoo/dev/dev.py

  import pkgfoo
  from importlib import reload
  reload(pkgfoo)

  # Does this work?
  pf.bar.baz()
  ```

  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to make available any changes I've made to the package code since I last restarted the REPL.
- I've looked at creating a keyboard shortcut to restart python and import my package, but I have no idea how I'd set this up so that:

  - It works for any project with a package structure, not just `pkgfoo`
  - It first runs `quit()` if the python REPL is already running

Comment: use ctrl+d to quit python. use history shortcuts to re-run previous commands in your shell and Python interpreter (up arrow key). maybe look into interactive windows (cell code magic) / jupyter notebooks. you should be able to put your import command in the same line as invoking the Python interpreter with `-c` or something.

Comment: Thanks  Ctrl+d is helpful. I don't particularly want to use jupyter to be honest... What I really want is a python script I can run and then play with in the REPL. Having to record everything I do in a notebook would feel more cumbersome than my current workflow. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: If you want to make sure things are working, why not write an actual test suite (using e.g [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/), etc)?

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not looking for something to replace testing (I do this as part of normal development anyway), but rather for ways people use the REPL to facilitate development alongside other practices (like unit testing). Based on the current lack of responses here, perhaps this just isn't something people do. I'm coming from R where this use of the REPL is pretty standard, so perhaps I just need to shift my mindset.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `-i` argument to Python? You can run `python -i somefile.py` and it will load in the contents of `somefile.py` first, then drop you to an interactive prompt. I use this for trying things out all the time; you can populate `somefile.py` with whatever setup code you need so that you can immediately start working at the REPL.

Comment: I wasn't aware - this is probably the most useful response so far! Thank you 

Comment: @wurli there's a lot of things to dislike about Haskell as a professional developer, but `ghci` is one of the best repls I've ever used. `stack ghci` loads a REPL with your module imported into it, and `:r` reloads from src. I miss it going back to Python.

Comment: Have you used ipython? I thought this might help. You can open it by typing `ipython` in the terminal.